# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource employee.hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi  I am getting the exception :

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource employee.hbm.xml

employee.hbm.xml is:

here is the tablepersubclass Hierarchy  configuration file:

```
<hibernate-mapping package = "com.javatpoint.mypackage">
    <class name = "Employee" table = "Employee">
        <id name = "id" column = "eid">
        <generator class = "increment"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name = "name"  column = "name"></property>

        <joined-subclass name = "Regular_Employee" table = "RegEmployee">
            <key column = "eid"></key>
            <property name = "salary" column = "salary"></property>
            <property name = bonus column = "bonus"> </property>
        </joined-subclass>

        <joined-subclass name = "Contract_Emloyee"  table = "ConEmployee">
            <key column = "eid"> </key>
            <property name = "pay_per_hour" name = "pay_per_hour"></property>
            <property name = "contract_duration" name = "contract_duration"></property>
        </joined-subclass>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and the configuration file hibernate.cfg.xml file is:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">mysql</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

Employee.java is:

```
package com.javatpoint.mypackage;

public class Employee {

private int id;
private String name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Contract_Employee.java is:

```
package com.javatpoint.mypackage;

public class Contract_Emloyee extends Employee{

private float pay_per_hour;
private String contract_duration;

public float getPay_per_hour() {
    return pay_per_hour;
}
public void setPay_per_hour(float pay_per_hour) {
    this.pay_per_hour = pay_per_hour;
}
public String getContract_duration() {
    return contract_duration;
}
public void setContract_duration(String contract_duration) {
    this.contract_duration = contract_duration;
}
```

}

Regular_Employee.java is :

```
package com.javatpoint.mypackage;

public class Regular_Employee extends Employee{

private float salary;
private int bonus;

public float getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(float salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public int getBonus() {
    return bonus;
}
public void setBonus(int bonus) {
    this.bonus = bonus;
}
```

}

Comment: This is just a poorly formatted dump of code, and doesn't explain exactly what problem you're having, what you've tried, and what guidance you want from Stack Overflow users.  If you think more about your question, and edit all the cruft away, you will likely get better answers.

Comment: Using a decent code IDE/editor with syntax highlighting would help you in detect such simple syntax errors.

Answer (score 4):

Your `employee.hbm.xml` is invalid xml.

```
<property name= bonus column="bonus"></property>
```

Change that to this:

```
<property name="bonus" column="bonus"></property>
```